# Which part is omitted in '...represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done in a diagram...'

Tags: grammar, meaning

From [Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.23.]

> We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is
> done in a diagram like [2] if we show the category to which each
> constituent belongs, as in [6].

Should it be detail(*than **detail** is represented in a diagram*), or the structure(*than **the structure** is represented in a diagram*)?

Syntactically, the detail is more appropriate,but,semantically,the structure is more appropriate.

Comment: Mr. Wang: Allow me to give you some advice. These authors are considered to be tops in the grammar field so I don't think one should try and edit what they are saying.  Also, I can't see what you mean clearly. You should write out the whole sentence. To do something in more detail than is done [in some place] is fine in English.

Comment: *than detail is represented in a diagram*? What do you mean?

Comment: By "omitted" OP is referring to what *virtually* fills the "slot" or "gap" in the comparative syntactic structure.

Comment: The original sentence is only marginally grammatical.  **given** or **supplied** or **presented** or **shown** or **provided** would work better than **done**.  It has to be the past participle of a transitive verb or an adjective formed therefrom.  I think the author had in mind "than is *typically* provided" and "done" is a synonym for that phrase. "That kind of thing is simply not done!".

Comment: The clue is the word "more" which indicates it's a comparison. More detail in X than in Y. Rewriting it with excess words is less good than understanding the structure.

Comment: @Lambie Instead of questioning, I tried to understand the grammatical structure of these sentences. Including a lot of the questions I asked before, they thought I was questioning. Maybe sometimes my words are not very accurate, which leads to some misunderstandings.

Comment: than is done [by the person who made the diagram]. It is passive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic structure is "We can (action) (comparison) than (method1) if we (method2)", so:

> We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done in a diagram like figure 2 if we show the category to which each constituent belongs.

Is broken down as

- "represent the structure of sentences" - action
- "in more detail" - comparison
- "[creating] a diagram like figure 2" - method1
- "show the category to which each constituent belongs" - method2

The clause "in more detail", as a whole, qualifies the action "represent the structure of sentences", and compares two methods of achieving that.

Grammatically, the comparison could be replaced, like "using fewer colours", or even just "better".

Compare a much simpler example:

> We can move ourselves faster than by walking if we run

- "move ourselves" - action
- "faster" - comparison
- "by walking" - method1
- "run" - method2

Comment: Comparisons call for using the word "more". You have listed two with no "more". to do something in **more detail than x**.

Comment: @Lambie I don't understand. Are you saying that "running is faster than walking" is not a comparison? Is there some other word I should have used rather than "comparison", that would cover the category including both "faster" and "in more detail"?

Comment: Never mind. I'm having trouble with *move ourselves faster*. That does sound weird. You do not fully explain: x in more detail **than** x. In fact, you don't directly address it at all...

Answer (score 0):

Consider someone talking about how to make a painting of a fish:

> We can render (the appearance of the fish) ( in a more realistic style) than was *done* on this painting to my left, if we apply some silver paint.

With "than was *done*", the comparand must be the entire verb phrase "render the appearance of the fish in a more realistic style". **do** is semantically anchored to the verb.

If we choose a different verb, for example, "than was used" or "than was employed", the comparand becomes "style".  **was employed** is anchored to what was employed, the style.

> We can render (the appearance of the fish) ( in a more realistic style) than was *employed* on this painting to my left, if we apply some silver paint.

I personally find the "done" version somewhat awkward, as the semantic focus is on the style chosen to render a realistic appearance, not the action of rendering a realistic appearance per se.

Comment: There really is nothing to criticize. Unless there is a typo or some egregious grammar thing (unlikely for these authors), I would be very careful in trying to criticize them...

Comment: @Lambie  Be as careful as you like.  I used the word "personally", and that's enough to say it's my opinion, and merely an opinion. And I feel it is not hubristic of me to hold an opinion on the matter.

Comment: In any case, I would never say "on a painting" for "in a painting". On a canvas, in a painting.

Comment: Ah, but you see "in" is from the perspective of the viewer, whereas "on" is from the perspective of the painter.

Comment: "But when I sit there and try to fabricate a technique on a painting – for example, try to paint like Fechin – well, it just comes off as false."  https://boldbrush.com/blog/170208/visual-inspiration-an-interview-with-dan-gerhartz

Comment: Viewer: What do you like about what you see in that painting? Don't heap scorn on that painting.

Comment: That link is discussing the surface of the canvas, but you were not. Unfortunately, this kind of thing does not work by googling it.

Comment: My sentence is talking about *applying* paint.

Comment: You actually do not even deal directly with the question as asked.

Comment: @Lambie I believe I do.  By "omitted" OP is referring to what fills the "gap" or "slot".

Comment: In your explanation, "the comparand must be the entire verb phrase "render the appearance of the fish in a more realistic style", do is semantically anchored to the verb. " Can't the comparand  be 'the appearance of...'? Why to bring the verb 'render'?

Comment: *We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than in a diagram like [2] if we show the category to which each constituent belongs, as in [6].* should also be ok?

Comment: @Mr.Wang  You're changing the structure of the sentence by omitting "is done".  I was commenting on the structure of the original and taking that structure as a given.  The specific problem I was focusing on is the phrase "in more detail than is *done*".   The past participle of a transitive verb is needed there, like "presented" or "shown". I was trying to make the best sense of that verb, "done", if it were left "as is", in the first part of my answer. "done" hearkens back to "present" but it isn't transitive as "present" is.

Comment: Is there a rule to determine who is "comparand" in a comparison clause introduced by "than"? My previous understanding was that the noun after "more" was "comparand". According to your interpretation, it seems that you are determining "comparand" (render the appearance of the fish in a more realistic style) based on the "done" in the comparison clause. Can you give some advice on how to determine "comparand"?

Comment: Here's how I understand the comparands: *We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than [the structure of sentences is represented in detail] in a diagram like [2]....*  Part of the complexity here is that we have a mix of active voice and passive voice.   Let's rephrase to have both in the passive voice:  *The structure of sentences can be represented in more detail than [the structure of sentences is represented in detail] in a diagram like [2]...*    **The structure of sentences can be represented in more detail than [detail] is given in a diagram like [2]...**

Answer (score -2):

Sample sentence:
We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done in a diagram like [2] if we show the category to which each constituent belongs, as in [6].

**Answer to the OP's question**: Nothing is omitted in "represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done in a diagram like [2] if we show the category to which each constituent belongs, as in [6]."

*Possible* synonyms for *done* if one must use one:

We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done in a diagram like [2] if we show the category to which each constituent belongs, as in [6].

- in more detail than is *used* in a diagram like [2]
- in more detail than is *shown* in a diagram like [2]

to do something in more detail than is done, used or shown in [some thing] is idiomatic in English.

Comment: If not omitted, what is the subject of 'is' in "than is done", detail?

Comment: Just saying something "is idiomatic" isn't very helpful to learners. What does the idiom mean? What are some other examples, rather than copying the example from the question twice?

Comment: @IMSoP If something is idiomatic, there is no need to rewrite it. However, it can be restated to show what it means in another way. The OP asked if something was omitted in the sentence. Answer: No, nothing is omitted.

Comment: @Lambie I am suggesting that "restating to show what it means" would be useful to a someone learning English, which is who this site is for. Without that, you're just saying "you've understood the sentence wrong" without giving them a chance to understand it better.

Comment: @Mr.Wang  "We can represent the structure of sentences in more detail than is done [passive verb: by the person who did the diagram] in a diagram like 2"=the structure of sentences

Comment: @IMSoP The question was "Ss anythng omitted in the sentence?" The answer is no, and sometimes one just has to accept how things are. I explained about the passive. More would be eggs in one's beer...